# Integer solution of equation

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory

I was thinking about different types of equations in two variables. My motivation for this is purely intrinsic. I just wanted to know what we can say about analytic methods of solving different equations. On the course of this, I came across the following:

> $5^x - 3^y = 2$

My guess is that the only solution in the positive integers is $x=y=1$. Also Wolfram Alpha is telling me that. Is there a way of approaching this problem.

Of course we can write $y = \frac{\log(5^x - 2)}{\log(3)}$, but I am not sure that this helps.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For integer solutions, I believe this is in general a very hard problem. However, for general solutions involving equations with exponents, maybe it will be helpful to check out the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: I am not sure whether the negative result about the solvability of Hilbert's problem already occurs in two variables, but there is no easy way to solve them in general.

Comment: I hope this answers your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: Thank you! Is it at least true that the above equation has only this one solution?

Comment: As far as I am aware , Catalan’s conjecture  was proved in 2002 by Preda Mihăilescu. So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: But does Catalan not only say something about consecutive prime powers?

Comment: There is a conjecture that $x^a-y^b=n$ only has finite many solutions for every positive integer $n$ (Pillai's conjecture). But this has only be proven for $n=1$ (in this case $(9/8)$ is the only solution). However, the above equation is so special that someone will probably find a proof that $(1/1)$ is in fact the only solution.

Comment: For $n\le 10^5$ , $2+3^n$ is not a perfect power, so we can safely assume that $(1/1)$ is the only solution.

Comment: I guess according to the wiki article that I provided Catalan conjecture is about the difference between powers of two natural numbers , not necessarily primes. Pillai’s conjecture generalizes it by  introducing more coefficients, like $mx^a-ny^b=r$ (say)

Comment: @Peter: Why can't it be a perfect power for bigger n?

Comment: I guess you can find a lot of discussion of this spirit in this math overflow thread, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69253/are-there-any-solutions-to-2n-3m-1

Comment: I have no proof, but it is very unlikely that such large solutions exist, this is what I mean with "safely".

Comment: I believe I have a solution to this problem now; it is by no means easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we start with some modulus arguments. If we take the whole sequence modulo $3$, then we have that $5^x\equiv2$. In particular, $x\equiv1\pmod2$. Similarly, taking the sequence modulo $5$ tells us that $y\equiv1\pmod2$ as well.

The next step is to write $5^{x+1}=p^2$ and $3^{y-1}=q^2$. The equation then becomes, after multiplication by $5$, $$p^2-15q^2=10.$$ This is a generalised pell equation, for which the solutions are given [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) (Theorem 3.3). In particular, we solve the pell equation $$a^2-db^2=1$$ for $d=15$, which yields a primitive solution $(4,1)$, and then find all solutions to $$x^2-dy^2=n$$ for $n=10$ such that $|x|\le \sqrt{10(4+\sqrt{15})}\approx8.9$.

The only such solution, as you may have guessed, is $(5,1)$.

Finally, we compose the two solutions to find all solutions to the original equation, $$p^2-15q^2=10.$$ This is a simple recurrence, beginning with initial term $p_0=5,q_0=1$ with the conditions $$p_{n+1} = 4p_n + 15q_n,\\q_{n+1}=p_n+4q_n.$$

The trick to notice here is that this sequence can hardly ever have a power of $5$ as $p_n$ (which was, after all, the original question!) so we restrict ourselves to looking at powers of $5$. A straightforward induction tells us that $p_n$ satisfies $p_0=5,p_1=35,$ and $$p_{n+2}=8p_{n+1}-p_{n}$$ which is handy.

If you think about the condition that we don't want any other factors other than $5$ to appear, this sounds awfully reminiscent of [Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem#Generalizations) -- indeed, the generalisation to Lucas sequences instantly reduces it to the finite case of $n\le30$.

```
>>> def is_power_of_5(n):
        while n%5==0:
            n//=5
        return n==1

>>> arr = [5,35]

>>> for i in range(40):
        arr.append(arr[-1]*8-arr[-2])

>>> for i in arr:
        if is_power_of_5(i):
            print(i)    
5
```

Hence $(1,1)$ is indeed the only solution to the question.